# Return Multiple items with the .filter() method - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

If I have an array with a set of numbers, and want to remove certain ones with the .filter method, I understand how to do this in when i need to remove a single item (or if i can use a mathematical expression), but can't get it to work with multiple items either purely by their value or position in the array.

In the following code I would like the new array selection to return the numbers 10, 12, 15

Also, I do need to do this with the filter() method only.

JS

```
let random = [4, 10, 12, 15, 30];
let selection = random.filter(function(num){

  return num === [10, 12, 30];

});
```

Comment: Read upon switch-case mechanism

Comment: `return [10, 12, 30].includes(num);` or `[10, 12, 30].indexOf(num) > -1`

Comment: If you want to return 10, 12, 15, why does your example say 10, 12, 30? Which set of numbers do you want to filter out? Do they have a common link?

Comment: What I'm saying is if you already know what values you want, why go through the hassle of filtering them from a longer array. Just set up a new array with those values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `includes`:

```js
let random = [4, 10, 12, 15, 30, 10, 10, 12, 5];
let selection = random.filter(function(num){
  var good = [10, 12, 30]
  return good.includes(num);
});

console.log(selection)
```

Of if you prefer the terseness of arrow function:

```js
let random = [4, 10, 12, 15, 30, 10, 10, 12, 5];
let selection = random.filter(num => [10, 12, 30].includes(num))
console.log(selection)
```

Comment: What's the point of filtering them out if you can simply use: `var good = [10, 12, 30]`? This isn't an issue with your code, rather the question in general.

Comment: @Andy - Not sure what the point is. I can imagine a scenario with a large input array and a handful of 'good' values. Imagine say an large array of animals and a small array that has mammals. Now I want to filter my large array to return only mammals as defined by my small array (or maybe some less contrived example :) )

Comment: But that's my point. You can only filter out those mammals _if you have existing list of mammals_ for reference. And if you have that list why go through the effort? It's quite late here. Maybe I should put the laptop down :)

Comment: @Mark_M if that's the case then you wouldn't know the array to check `includes` against so this answer doesn't apply. What Andy is saying is that if OP already knows all values then why not just use them? If OP didn't know them, then this answer would be no help.

Comment: @Andy list: `[ant, fly, horse, cat, horse, lizard, dog, cat, dog, ant]` mammals: `[horse, cat, dog, cat, elephant]` Returning mammals is *not* the same as returning the filtered list.

Comment: You either have a list, or the data that passes through the `filter` function _satisfies a specific condition_ (ie is greater than 4). Satisfying the condition of being in a array just leaves you with two arrays that are exactly the same.

Comment: @Li357 I updated my answer so it's clearer that this isn't the same as just returning the filter criteria.

Comment: Yup, that's better. I just did the same thing in my head. I am now satisfied.

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if I do not understand it correctly, but if what you're looking for is to filter an array by the item's index, you can use the second parameter passed to the `filter` method's callback, which is the `index`.

```js
let random = [4, 10, 12, 15, 30];
let selection = random.filter(function(num, index){
  return index > 0 && index < 4;
});
console.log(selection);
```

Comment: `let selection = random.slice(1, 4);`

Comment: @4castle That works too. :)

Although the above code would allow for more control than a simple, trusted slice.

Answer (score 0):

You do need a condition that will return true or false when using filter, so the simplest way to do this with the filter method would be:

```
let random = [4, 10, 12, 15, 30];
let selection = random.filter(function(num){

if (num > 4 && num < 16) {return true};

});
```

The other way to do it would be filtering by position in the array and that would be better achieved with other array methods.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question you want a function that takes a an array, checks if the elements are in your larger array and if they are there, removes them.

Filter might not be your best choice here because it doesn't alter the original array, it only makes a new array. Try using splice.

```js
let random = [4, 10, 12, 15, 30];
function remove(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(random.includes(array[i])){
      random.splice(random.indexOf(array[i]), 1)
    }
  }
}

remove([10, 12, 30]);
console.log(random); // [4, 15]
```

I am assuming you want to remove because if you already know which elements you want why filter them out? why not just pass them into your function as a new array? filter will create a new array anyways.

But if you would like to remove elements from your first array the answer above might help.